# SwiftUI - How can I blur the default background color of a view?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, xcode11

no code to show here, but I would like to know how it may be possible to do this. I have tried to use

```
.blur(radius: (20)
```

on a view, but it tends to blur the entire view. Including the text, and anything else in the view. The default background color is fine and I don't want/need to change it (in order to keep the app compatible with light/dark mode). I want to make the view's background slightly blurred/opaque, but I want the text and buttons in the view to still remain full and normal. Is there any way possible to just blur the background color of the view itself?

Comment: Isn't it possible to add a UIVisualEffectView as a childView here?

Comment: You can check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610957/is-there-a-method-to-blur-a-background-in-swiftui

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to apply blur directly to background only, like in the example below

```
Button("Test") {}
        .background(Color.red.blur(radius: 20))
```

[image: blur button]

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Is it possible to do it without specifying the color of the rectangle? I noticed yours was red. If not I will most likely just blur grey.