# How can I have a Blur effect as a Background in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to have blur effect as background for my View, as we know, we can blur the view and what is inside, but I do't want blur content of view but I want blur background view to give a glassy blurred through effect as we know. How i can do this in SwiftUi?

In other words, the under layer of view would be blurred in frame on current view which sets as background for current view.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59527255/12299030? Or in this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301261/12299030?

Comment: Do you mean to have the look like the image you posted? If so, that is a shadow, not a blur. Does this help?: [https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-draw-a-shadow-around-a-view](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-draw-a-shadow-around-a-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 15 you can use Materials, like *.ultraThinMaterial*

```
.background(.ultraThinMaterial)
```

But from iOS 14 down, there is no SwiftUI way to achieve this, though it is possible to create an UIViewRepresentable and place it as a background.

Following code will create a UIViewRepresentable that you are able to use as a background: *.systemUltraThinMaterial* can be changed to any material

```
import SwiftUI
struct BlurView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemUltraThinMaterial
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}
```

View extension (optional):

```
extension View {
    func backgroundBlurEffect() -> some View {
        self.background(BlurView())
    }
}
```

Then use on a view like a pop up.

```
.background(BlurView())
```

or if used like extension

```
.backgroundBlurEffect()
```

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5ANp.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
.blur(radius: showCustomAlertView ? 5 : 0)//<< here comes your blur
```

on your view to blur the view.

[image]

Comment: @ davidev : thanks a lot for your code, but I already now that code, I wanted the alert area get blur not all screen

Comment: Okay.. miss understood it then. Let me check again and edit my post